# Android Studio Grid Layout Not Working Properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gridlayout

I am trying to make a grid of pictures with 2 columns and 3 rows. However my screen shows only one item.I am not sure why.

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

And this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is my code so far. I was following a tutorial on YouTube and I have rechecked multiple times. I'm still not sure what's wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="10"
  tools:context=".Interests">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGrid"
        style="@style/HeaderStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Select your interests"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:padding="14dp"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_walking_with_dog">

            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:text="Dog Walking"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"

        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_walking_with_dog"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:text="Dog Walking"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"

        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_walking_with_dog"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:text="Dog Walking"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


  </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Some help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the **ROW** and **COLUMN** of GridLayout children correctly. Try to set like below:

**First Child with 0,0:**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"

    ...>
```

**Second Child with 0,1:**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1"

    ...>
```

**Third Child with 1,0:**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"

    ...>
```

**Fourth Child with 1,1:**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1"

    ...>
```